# Why Don't Visualforce Wrapper Class Getter/Setter Methods Not Exist?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, inner-class

I have a wrapper/inner class like so:

```
public class parameter{

    public String source { get; set; }
    public Integer year { get; set; }
    public String field { get; set; }

    public parameter(String source, Integer year, String field){
        this.source = source;
        this.year = year;
        this.field = field;
    }

}
```

Now from a method in the base class if I attempt to get one of these attributes like so:

```
private String getValue(Parameter p){
    String test1 = p.getSource();
    Integer test2 = p.getYear();
    String test3 = p.getField();
}
```

I the following error:

> Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature

If I attempt to make the attributes static I get reminded that only outer-classes can have static attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `source`, `Year` and `Field` are variable then Just use `p.source`, `p.Year` and `p.Field`

```
String test1 = p.getSource();
Integer test2 = p.getYear();
String test3 = p.getField();
```

Instead try

```
String test1 = p.source;
Integer test2 = p.Year;
String test3 = p.Field;
```

---

If you create a method like

```
public class parameter{

    public String source { get; set; }
    public Integer year { get; set; }
    public String field { get; set; }

    public parameter(String source, Integer year, String field){
        this.source = source;
        this.year = year;
        this.field = field;
    }

    public String getSource(){
      return 'test ';
    }    
}
```

then use

```
p.Source();
```

Comment: Literally just did this right as your answer came in. After I typed out my problem I saw it more clearly :P

Comment: It's often like that. If you're passing values in the constructor you can probably switch to `private set`. @Xtremefaith